# Placing a marker within the image

Tags: java, swing, markers

i have written a code which displays an image in a tabbed pane. My code lookes like this

```
  class tracker extends JPanel 
  {
       String imageFile = "areal view.JPG";
       public tracker()
       {
          super();
       }

       public tracker(String image)
        {
             super();
              this.imageFile = image;
        }
       public tracker(LayoutManager layout)
           {
              super(layout);
            }
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                             /*create image icon to get image*/
               ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imageFile));
               Image image = imageicon.getImage();

                             /*Draw image on the panel*/
                super.paintComponent(g);

                 if (image != null)
                     g.drawImage(image, 100, 50, 700, 600, this);
                   //g.drawImage(image, 100, 50, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }
  }
```

Well then i need to place a marker on certain  position of the image .. How to place a marker on it.. ?

I tried Googling it, but came to know that it only works with Android and in web applications. Is it true??

I don't believe with it, as Java does all!!!!!...

Once i came-forth with the `BufferedImage` concept but it doesn't work so..

Any kind of help regarding placing a marker within the image is welcome....

Comment: `as java does all!!!!!...` huuuh, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, before that read Oracles tutorial about Painting in Swing, search here on this forum

Answer (score 5):

You could try painting something onto the `Graphics`.

You shouldn't be loading images inside the `paint` method, this will only slow down the repaints and potentially consume more resources.  Load the image once and maintain a reference to it.

```
class Tracker extends JPanel 
{
   String imageFile = "areal view.JPG";
   private Image image;

   public Tracker()
   {
      super();
      init();
   }

   public Tracker(String image)
   {
       super();
       this.imageFile = image;
       init();
   }

   public Tracker(LayoutManager layout)
   {
       super(layout);
       init();
   }

   protected void init() {
       ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imageFile));
       image = imageicon.getImage();
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       if (image != null) {
           g.drawImage(image, 100, 50, 700, 600, this);
           g.setColor(Color.RED);
           g.fillOval(290, 215, 20, 20);
       }                  
    }
}
```

I'd recommend that you take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

**Update with additional example**

From you comments, I would suggest using a [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).  It will allow you to place custom components at arbitrary locations over your image.

[image]

```
public class Tracker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tracker();
    }

    public Tracker() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                // 247x178

                MapPane mapPane = new MapPane();
                Marker marker = new Marker();
                marker.setToolTipText(
                                "<html><table><tr><td valign=top><img src='" + getClass().getResource("/Earth.png") + "'>" +
                                "</td><td valign=top><b>Earth</b><br>Mostly Harmless</td></tr></table></html>"
                                );

                marker.setSize(marker.getPreferredSize());
                marker.setLocation(237, 188 - marker.getHeight());
                mapPane.add(marker);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(mapPane);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Marker extends JLabel {

        public Marker() {
            try {
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Marker.png"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class MapPane extends JLayeredPane {

        private BufferedImage map;

        public MapPane() {
            try {
                map = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/SolarSystem.jpg"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return map == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (map != null) {
                g.drawImage(map, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is displaying a oval(point) at that location, which is static and it doesn't show any message when a mouse pointer is placed on it. just like marker in the google maps!! Is there any possibility????

Comment: *"Is there any possibility"* - lots.  I would be helpful to have some idea of what it is you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @ram You need to be clear in you questions as to what it is you want and you are having trouble with.  I've added an additional example

Comment: sorry, i was in hurry!!! hey actually i have previously worked out with this kind of markers concept. But i broke down when a repeated errors occurred, i thought it was erroneous trying markers in java. But, this time the similar errors are striking me with your part of code, while the execution enters run(): in the catch block it shows the errors as identifier expected. What might be the problem???

Comment: hey!!!! i got it... after a long work it was done, missed some class connections thanq...