# JLabel - Show longer text as multiple lines?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So say I have a really long line that I want to display in a `JLabel`. How can I do it?

Currently, longer lines come up as this:

[image]

I have to resize the window to see the complete text.

How can I make it so that there's linebreaks when the text almost reaches the width of my `JFrame`?

I'm not sure if any code is required here for you to answer this, but still:

my frame properties:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(new Dimension(450, 400));
frame.setLocation(new Point(400, 300));
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

The label I want to modify:

```
question = new JLabel("Question:");
question.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
question.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

EDIT:
More details:

I am reading lines from a file and then displaying them. The size of lines is not fixed, and so I do not know where to put `<br>` at.

EDIT 2:

I ended up using `JTextArea`.

```
private JTextArea textAreaProperties(JTextArea textArea) {
    textArea.setEditable(false);  
    textArea.setCursor(null);  
    textArea.setOpaque(false);  
    textArea.setFocusable(false);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    return textArea;
}
```

Comment: You may find the second example of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705684/placing-a-marker-within-the-image/14705893#14705893) helpful. It uses HTML to provide extended layout to a tool tip, but the concept is the same

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just another example, showing that, with the right layout manager, text wrapped in `HTML` tags will automatically wrap to the available space...

[image]

```
public class TestHTMLLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestHTMLLabel();
    }

    public TestHTMLLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
                sb.append("<html>I have something to say, it's beter to burn out then to fade away.").
                                append("  This is a very long String to see if you can wrap with in").
                                append("the available space</html>");

                JLabel label = new JLabel(sb.toString());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setSize(100, 100);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }    
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: That's way too much work for what I need. I ended up using `JTextArea`. See my edit in OP.

Comment: Adding "<html>" to the start and "</html>" to the end of `String` is to much work??  Wow, you're going to be disappointed :P

Comment: The problem I see with this kind of solution is that when dynamically fetched text which already contains html tags, for example for markup, will not display at all (no text will show up) as the <html> and </html> tags are both added twice. It really is a pity that a JLabel doesn't support multiline out of the box.

Comment: @Timmos In that case, you wouldn't need to set it up yourself.  If you think that you "might" get a html ladden `String` you could also check for it (`String#startsWith`)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You would need to do that check everywhere you need a (multiline)label... For such basic functionality, I prefer reusable code, thus an out-of-the-box component that does it for me. But you are right of course, I just don't consider this a very elegant solution.

Comment: @Timmos Okay, so make a factory method, create a custom label..."out-of-the-box" functionality got us the `JSpinner` and `JFormattedFields`, which are great at the jobs they do but so inflexible as to be more frustrating then they are worth (IMHO)

Answer (score 11):

Use HTML to display the text within the Label.

```
JLabel fancyLabel = new JLabel("<html>Punch Taskmaster</html>");
```

(Taskmaster-suggested example added in)

Comment: Added an example, earn a up-vote (I know, I'm such a task master :))

Comment: `<br>` is where it's at bro.

Comment: @Legend Just wrapping the text in HTML should afford line wrapping functionality under the right layout manager...BUT, <br> isn't going to hurt ;)

Comment: The thing about `<br>` is that I am reading a lot of content, and I do not know where tag needs to be at.

Comment: @user2027425 If you are not sure then better take a look at answer given by madProgrammer.

Answer (score 5):

Format with HTML. Works great.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(450, 400));
        frame.setLocation(new Point(400, 300));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JLabel question = new JLabel("<html>Question:<br>What is love?<br>Baby don't hurt me<br>Don't hurt me<br>No more</html>");
        question.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
        question.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        frame.add(question);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind when someone says the word 'Question' lol

Answer (score 4):

Something like this. The answer give by rcook is very correct. Its just example to show how it can be done.

```
 b1 = new JLabel("<html>Default Lable I have to resize the
                 <br/> window to see the complete text.</html>");
```