# How to add a new line every set number of chars in a swing JLabel

Tags: java, string, swing

Basically, the question says it all, I want to add a new line every...40-50 chars for a string which I never know how big it is exactly. Thank you for the help

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737810/jlabel-show-longer-text-as-multiple-lines/14738193#14738193).  I'd be less worried about setting the limit and simply allowing the UI to make decisions for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the text in `<html> </html>` and then use `.setMaximumSize` and it should work

Since your do not wish to change the maximum size of the label, Try it in the HTML

```
 jLabel1.setText("<html><body width=200>some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string some reallly long string</body></html>");
```

where

```
width=200
```

relates to 200 pixels wide

Comment: s you're saying I should do string s = "<html>"+ text + "</html>" and then setMaximumSize in the panel?

Comment: Set the size on the jLabel, and then html will just wrap

Comment: Apply a preferred/maximum/minimum size to any component is no recommended.  It's to easy to be ignore or changed...

Comment: There are ways to fix it. You could also set a body width inside the html. The max will not be ignored, and if you want to fix it over ride the class and call it final

Comment: So then what should I do MadProgrammer? basically, I want to limit it to a space, and it to keep having new lines each time it reaches the limit

Comment: The easiest way would to be as i said, wrap in HTML and set the max size, if your worried about someone over riding your max, Then you should override jlabel and make the dimensions fixed.

Comment: @User2189708 The question really is, why? You could simply use a non-editable text area instead