# Display an array of objects in a GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am working on a program that is supposed to track the inventory of Blu-ray movies.  I have stored the movies in an object array (the array stores the name, ID, number of discs, and price of each movie).  I know ArrayLists are a more efficient way of storing the objects in an array, but for the purpose of this assignment I am required to use an array.  I have previously had this program print out to the console with not problem, but I'm trying to add this program to a GUI.  I have already written a class for the GUI, but I cannot figure out how to add the arrays to the JPanel and JFrame.

Here is my GUI class:

```
class TextInFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel greeting;
    private JLabel inventoryUnsorted;
    private JPanel panel;

    public TextInFrame(){
        super("Blu-ray Movie Inventory");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        panel = new JPanel();
        greeting = new JLabel(BluRay.programGreeting());
        add(greeting);
        greeting.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        greeting.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.add(greeting);
        this.add(panel);
   }
}
```

Here is a portion of my main method that has the

```
public class Inventory {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TextInFrame window = new TextInFrame();
    window.setSize(600, 600);

    BluRay[] movies = new BluRay[5];

    movies[0] = new BluRay("Man of Steel", "48461", 24, 17.99);
    movies[1] = new BluRay("Fast Five", "84624", 10, 12.99);
    movies[2] = new BluRay("Batman Begins", "15483", 19, 13.98);
    movies[3] = new BluRay("X-Men", "48973", 6, 15.99);
    movies[4] = new BluRay("The Outsiders", "01893", 16, 9.98);

    String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(movies, movies.length, String[].class);


    // loop to print through the BluRay movies array
    for (String string : stringArray) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

Every time I try to add the array into a JLabel or JPanel, I get the error "BluRay[] cannot be converted to String".  I am completely stumped on how to get this information in the GUI.  I am also having trouble with the greeting in the JPanel.  It is not wrapping when the JFrame is resized.  STUMPED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), they will allow you to display arrbitraty objects in a list on the GUI

Check out [Creating a Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) in particular

`JLabel` doesn't wrap it's content by default.  You could use a `JTextArea` set to non-editable and modify the background color and border or simply wrap the text of the `JLabel` in `<HTML>` tags...add us a different layout manager ;)

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737810/jlabel-show-longer-text-as-multiple-lines/14738193#14738193)