# JButton over Image in JFrame - swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have an opened an image using JFrame in java. Now I want to display a button at particular location in that image to do certain task. But i feel it to be more challenging. Please give me an idea or source code to do my task.

waiting for valuable reply

Comment: This is going to require some effort. If you want to display the button at a particular location, you're going to need to take over the control of the job of the layout manager

Comment: You could take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705684/placing-a-marker-within-the-image/14705893#14705893)

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a JComponent and use a MouseListener to see if the user clicks in the area of the image. Thus you can execute your action if the user clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [LayeredPane layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). This will easily overlay a button on a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to just add a click the image to run the command you want just like button use mouse listener. or just prompt a JOption pane for options for the Image?